# maven dependency management from parent pom overrides ${project.version}

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent pom with a dependency management like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>art1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>art1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The artifacts art1 and art2 are submodules from the same module and they inherit from the parent pom where the dependency management is.

The dependencies from art1 looks like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>art2</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For now I tought that if the project version of art1 was 0.5 the version of art2 in the dependency of art1 would be 0.5
But it seems that the dependencyManagement override the ${project.version}

Can you tell me if I am right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Specified versions in dependency management from parent pom will have "priority" to transitive dependencies.
This is one of the purposes of dependencies management: user can "force" somehow the versions of dependencies in a single place.

Comment: Can you like some documentation about this purpose? Then I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: As a best practice, you should specify all your dependencies versions in parent pom, dependency management section. It will be much simpler to change a version, since you know all dependencies versions are declared in one single place.